# Does one “take” a photocopy or “make” a photocopy?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

If the verb for "photograph" is *take*, I presume that the verb for a "photographic copy" should also be *take*.

The word *photocopy* is often abbreviated to *copy*. I have noticed the verb *make* is used for *copy*.

Considering the above, which is used more: to *make* a copy or *take* a copy?

Comment: Unlike ***take** a photograph*, where ***make*** is rarely used, either verb works with *photocopy* (as with ***make/take** notes*). But if Google Books estimates are to be believed, ***make** a photocopy* is significantly more common than the *take* version.

Comment: I don't think your analogy holds. In the pre-digital (and pre-Polaroid) photography era, there was significant time between when you _took_ the picture, and when you _saw_ the picture. In fact, the process of _making_ the picture was quite complicated; "picture making" had at least three steps: taking the picture, developing the film, and making the print. In Xeroxing, the image must be scanned before it is printed, but the time between the two is small enough that _make a photocopy_ seems to work just fine, where as _make a picture_ didn't – at least, not while you were holding the camera.

Comment: @J.R. but if it only *takes* less than a second to snap a photo, nowadays it takes one or two seconds (or even less depending on the model) to *take* a copy. If you think about it, "to do a copy" is almost like taking a photo. There's no lengthy time process involved in producing a facsimile/photocopy/copy. But we say "make a copy", and not "take" (See Martin Smith's comment). Perhaps we should look at it as the machine that "takes" a photo of the text/image.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't understand the point you're trying to make.

Comment: @thomas before cameras went digital, we said "take a photo", to "make a photo" involved a long process (see J.R. comment above). I'm saying that the period between the device taking an image, and developing it, now takes seconds in a photocopier machine. In other words there is no solid logic to justify "make a copy" vs. "take a copy". Perhaps one way of looking at it is that we *make* the machine *take a photo*, and we receive a hard copy in our hands.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I agree with you. *Take* to me suggests something that happens rapidly, whilst *make* sounds like a much more drawn-out affair.

Comment: Make, take a photocopy/copy: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+a+photocopy%2Cmake+a+copy%2Ctake+a+photocopy%2C+take+a+copy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20photocopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20copy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20photocopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20copy%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Hmmm ...  What's a "photocopy"?

Comment: @J.R. Is it time to champion 'make a photograph'?

Comment: @Edwin - I might say that – if I was carrying my memory stick to a local store to get a few prints made. Snapping the shutter, though, is still _taking_ the photograph.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - All true, but when we photocopy something, the user doesn't really care about the "taking a photo" part of the process, only about the "making the copy" part of the process. Both photography and xeroxing are take-and-make processes; in the former, the _taking_ part has the most human involvement, while in the latter, _taking_ the photograph is simply a means to an end.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're confusing taking a photograph with making a print. It's an entirely separate process. I "take a photograph" the instant I click the button and a photographic impression is recorded on the film. The phrase has never applied to the entire process.

Comment: @thomas No, I'm not confusing anything. It's **to take a photograph**, when you use a camera. You **develop** a film roll.

Comment: You re-posted 'I was hoping for academic analysis and reasoning. Not a social-Google-based one. I do not think that Google is a reliable source – and logic is the last thing that explains the choice of usage.' Were you hoping for a logical argument explaining why the normal usage should be considered 'wrong'?

Comment: @J.R. I was referring to the fact that now, in the digital (and Polaroid) photography era, there is not significant time between when you take the picture, and when you see the picture.

Comment: @Edwin - I got that. But, at least in my mind, "making" conjures up an image of a physical print.

Comment: @J.R. But idioms and near-idioms – here delexical verb structures – tend to leave logic far behind (assuming there ever was any). Make / take a decision. Make a speech. Make one's mind up. Take a walk / a break / a bath.

Answer (score 13):

When you photograph something, you **take** a photo.

When you copy something, you **make** a copy.

When you copy something photographically and use the portmanteau word *photocopy* to  describe the process (and its result), you are using the noun-as-adjective *photo* to describe the noun *copy.*

Because *copy* is the chief element in this combination, it requires the same verb to describe the copying process as you would use for *copy* alone, namely *make:* so you **make** a photocopy.

Answer (score 2):

For copies,
"**make a copy**" is current usage.

You could also say "get a copy" or "print a copy".

"take a copy" sounds unusual.

Comment: Didn't sound that unusual to me but having Googled both phrases and reviewed the first few results the "make" ones do seem more relevant. The "take a copy" ones are often about physically carrying copies of documentation.

Comment: You could instruct someone else to "take a copy", implying that they get to keep the copy and don't have to give it back to you.